xml spring security basic authentication for soap webservice
the context is: a SAOP webservices builded inside SAP Commerce.
I want add the basic authentication for authorize the use of webserices.
Constraint: I can work only with spring xml configuration.
I added xxx-spring-security-config.xml and imported it with
   <import resource="config/xxx-spring-security-config.xml" /> into web-spring.xml
xxx-spring-security-config.xml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright (c) 2021 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company. All rights reserved.
-->
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <!-- <http pattern="/WEB-INF/500.jsp" security="none" /> -->
    <!-- <http pattern="/WEB-INF/404.jsp" security="none" /> -->
    <!-- <http pattern="/static/**" security="none" /> -->

    <http pattern="/securityNone"  security="none"/>
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" method="POST" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>


If I submit a request to my webserices (with correct credential, wrong credential or simply without credential) the result is always the same: my application receive the request and return a 200
My expectation is manage the basic auth.
I tried to broke the xxx-spring-security-config.xml (with a wrong formattation) and the webservices doesn't work anymore, so the xml is correctly imported.
